# Insert text in Tkinter Entrybox from Sqlite

Tags: python, tkinter

How can I insert text to my Entrybox from my sqlite data? When I type the Employee Number and press the "Enter Button" Employee Name and Department will automatically insert text from the database.[image]

[image]

Comment: How are you storing the rest of your data?

Comment: What is your problem? Don't know how to insert text into an entry? Don't know how to retrieve data from sqlite database?

Comment: This is convered in the standard documentation for the `Entry` widget. It's not clear why you need our help.

Comment: @BryanOakley I want to insert the Employee Name in the Entry Box from the Sqlite.

Comment: What's stopping you from doing that? Doing sqlite queries is well documented, and inserting data into an `Entry` widget is documented. What sort of problem are you having?

Comment: @BryanOakley I'm sorry I will try to read sqlite documentation.
This is I want to do:
Type the Employee Number and press the "Enter" button
The Employee Name and Department automatically fill the entry widget base on the Employee Number from the database.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.insert(0,info)` where info is the information you want to insert into the entry box. For example, if the employee name entry box is `name_entry` and the variable holding the employee's name is `e_name`, you would use `name-entry.insert(0, e_name)`. You can do something similar for each field you need to fill.

Comment: I'm trying to get the employee name from the sqlite database.